SQLite3 insertion speed
I need to do several hundred thousand insertions into a database on a daily basis.  I would prefer this took minutes rather than hours.
The SQLite documentation claims that 50,000 insertion / second should be achievable. https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q19
500,000 insertion should go faster than 10 seconds.
However, I cannot get more than 500 insertions per second.
Here is my test code:
#include <iostream>
#include "sqlite3.h"
#include "cRunWatch.h"

main()
{
    // initialize timer  https://ravenspoint.wordpress.com/2010/06/16/timing/

    raven::set::cRunWatch::Start();

    // construct sqlite3 database
    sqlite3 *db;
    char *dbErrMsg;
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;

    // open database
    sqlite3_open("test.dat", &db);

    // switch off synchronization
    // This command will cause SQLite to not wait on data to reach the disk surface
    sqlite3_exec(
        db,
        "PRAGMA synchronous=OFF",
        0, 0, &dbErrMsg);

    // create table for insertions
    sqlite3_exec(
        db,
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test "
        " ( v );",
        0, 0, &dbErrMsg);

    // prepare insertion statement
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(
        db,
        "INSERT INTO test "
        "VALUES ( ?1 );",
        -1,
        &stmt,
        0);

    // specify number of insertion to run
    const int count = 500;

    // specify all insertions to be done in one transaction
    sqlite3_exec(
        db,
        "START TRANSACTION",
        0, 0, &dbErrMsg);

    {
        // start timing execution of this scope
        raven::set::cRunWatch aWatcher("testInsert");

        // loop over insertions
        for (int k = 0; k < count; k++)
        {
            // bind insertion number to insertion value
            sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 1, k);

            // execute insertion
            int rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);

            // check for success
            if (rc != SQLITE_DONE)
                throw std::runtime_error(
                    "INSERT failed"                );

            // reset
            sqlite3_reset(stmt);

            // end insertion loop
        }

        // end timing scope
    }

    // end transaction
    sqlite3_exec(
        db,
        "END TRANSACTION",
        0, 0, &dbErrMsg);

    // report
    std::cout << count << " inserts\n";
    raven::set::cRunWatch::Report();

    return 0;
}

Build log, with O2 optimization switched on
g++ ./src/testInsert.cpp \
-c -o .vscode/obj/testInsert.o  -I../sqliteClass/src -I../../code_ext/sqlite -I../raven-set -I../../code_ext/boost/boost1_78  -std=c++17 -O2 -D_mingw_
gcc      -o .vscode/obj/sqlite3.o -c ../../code_ext/sqlite/sqlite3.c -O2
g++ ../raven-set/cRunWatch.cpp \
-c -o .vscode/obj/cRunWatch.o  -I../sqliteClass/src -I../../code_ext/sqlite -I../raven-set -I../../code_ext/boost/boost1_78  -std=c++17 -O2 -D_mingw_
g++ -O2 \
-o bin/test.exe .vscode/obj/testInsert.o .vscode/obj/sqlite3.o .vscode/obj/cRunWatch.o  \

Output
500 inserts
raven::set::cRunWatch code timing profile
Calls           Mean (secs)     Total           Scope
       1        0.94048         0.94048         testInsert

5000 total inserts
raven::set::cRunWatch code timing profile
Calls           Mean (secs)     Total           Scope
       1        10.3314 10.3314 testInsert

Is there some optimization I have missed that might give me two orders of magnitude performance boost?

Can I ask what exactly you're doing that needs so many insertions?

Are you testing with an optimized build? Performance-testing un-optimizd code is usually fairly pointless.

@SoronelHaetir  Yes, of course.  Notice -O2 in build log.

Have you tried a larger test? The overhead of the transaction might be exceeding the insert time

@SoronelHaetir While that's good advice in general, in a database application the bottleneck is almost always the DB library and disk, code optimization probably is not very significant.

You can generally speed up insertions by doing them in large batches: INSERT INTO tablename VALUES (?1), (?2), (?3), .... Rather than inserting one row at a time.

@AlanBirtles  Good question.  5,000 insertions take 10 seconds, so still 500 insertions / sec

@Barmar  The BEGIN/END TRANSACTIONS are supposed to deal with this, AFAIK

I insert multiple rows at a time and also use transactions.

Transactions deal with different issues.

Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711631/improve-insert-per-second-performance-of-sqlite ?

Writing a transaction log isn't free.   You can give up transactionality to make it go faster.

@duffymo  NOT SO.  Without grouping inserts into a transaction, the performance is painful.  Please read link at top of my question.

@Barmar  I have tried your suggestion.  Doing 5 inserts in one statement gives me a 5 times performance improvement ( 2500 inserts/sec).  Not enough for my needs, but a significant improvement.  Still wondering where the SQLite docs get 50,000 insert/sec.

50k inserts / second is abysmal. And as your source notes, based on HDD not SSD disk speeds. My laptop gets over 500k inserts / second when using sqlite3 from python.

The command to start a stransaction is BEGIN TRANSACTION.  I'm guessing START TRANSACTION statement fails, for invalid syntax, but you aren't checking for errors.

@IgorTandetnik  You got it!  That is the answer.  Post that as an answer and I will accept it.

Using the @IgorTandetnik fix, I am now getting 50,000 inserts in 10 milliseconds

How much memory does your machine have? What kind of storage is the database stored on? What CPU do you have?
